# highcharts symbols without connected lines

Tags: highcharts

I am using high charts as a graph solution, I need some styles I don't know if it is feasible. I tried different styles however I need to know how to insert symbols in http://www.highcharts.com as a graph without the connected lines, in other words I need to do a graph style that consists of only symbols is that feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use scatter series http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter

Edit: [custom marker](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker)

Comment: Yes, you can set marker by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker

Comment: I was wondering if we can have 2 graphs one dotted and the other lined

Comment: Yes in each series you need to define marker, like in the example above (demo/scatter).

Comment: In fact I want to end up with the following: [graph](http://www.wondereight.com/graph.png) a line and two types of dots

Comment: You can add as many series as you want, and for each series you can define whatever options you want. example:  http://jsfiddle.net/yPLVP/60/